# How to calculate the rate of quantity some rows to the quantity another rows in the same column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table

| ID | Key | Type | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a01 | a | AA |
| 2 | a02 | a | BB |
| 3 | a01 | a | AA |
| 4 | a03 | b | AA |
| 5 | a08 | b | BB |
| 6 | a12 | a | BB |
| 7 | a04 | b | AA |
| 8 | a07 | b | AA |

I need to create the report in Power BI with the following analytics:
Total quantity of Key by Type and Source divided by Total quantity of Key by Type, where Source = "BB"

I created the Measure

```
Rate =
VAR Qnt = 
CALCULATE(
  COUNT(table[Key]),
  ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Type], table[Source])
)

VAR Qnt_BB = 
CALCULATE(
  COUNT(table[Key]),
  ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Type], table[Source] = "BB")
)

DIVIDE(Qnt, Qnt_BB)
```

But it doesn't work.
Please advise.

I am expecting the following report.

| Type | Source AA | Source BB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2/3 | 3/3 |
| b | 3/1 | 1/1 |

Answer (score 0):

When you say it doesn't work - the results of the measure or the a formula syntax issue?

Below is the syntax correction of your measure:

```
Rate =
VAR Qnt = 
CALCULATE(
  COUNT(table[Key]),
  ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Type], table[Source])
)

VAR Qnt_BB = 
CALCULATE(
  COUNT(table[Key]),
  ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Type]),
  table[Source] = "BB" // moved out from the ALLEXCEPT
)

RETURN DIVIDE(Qnt, Qnt_BB) // added RETURN
```

And from your expected results table - is your first row correct?

| Type | Source AA | Source BB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2/3 - shouldn't this be 2/2 | 3/3 - shouldn't this be 2/2 |